# How get name of bone on mouse click in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can anyone tell me how get name of bone (in armature) on (for example) mouse click. 
Or at least how I can get list of bones by as3 code.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an armature link already. It has a rootJoint property, that returns an IKJoint object. You then recursively pass through its children via normal for() cycle:

```
var rj:IKJoint=yourArmature.rootJoint;
for (i=rj.numChildren-1;i>=0;i--) {
    trace(rj.getChildAt(i).bone.name);
}
```

But, IK is normally a tree, so with this you'll only get one layer of bones, so you will most likely need to walk deeper. So, make a recursive function that will call itself while an IKJoint has children.

```
function getBones(j:IKJoint):void {
    if (j==null) return; // no joint. Seems possible
    if (j.numChildren==0) return;
    for (i=j.numChildren-1;i>=0;i--) {
        var tj:IKJoint=j.getChildAt(i);
        var tb:IKBone=tj.bone;
        if ((tj==tb.headJoint)||(j==tb.headJoint)) getBones(tb.tailJoint);
            else getBones(tb.headJoint); 
        // parse the bone "tb" here
    }
}
```

Then you call this from root joint and have your list in a series of parses. I expect you will not get a bone at mouse click, as these are literally invisible, you'll only be able to get an element of the MovieClip with IK armature.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are looking for the IKManager class: [IKManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/ik/IKManager.html)

Something like this for example (trace the list of armatures):

```
for (var i=0; i < IKManager.numArmatures; i++){
    trace(IKManager.getArmatureAt(i).name);
}
```

Comment: This give me list of armatures, but I want list of bones.